# Java condition program

Tags: java

I am doing java programming practice from a website. I have to display this out put using arrays.

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student 1: 55
Enter the grade for student 2: 108
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 2: 56
Enter the grade for student 3: 57
The average is 56.0
```

This is my source code so far. It is showing results but not working properly. It takes number of students & grade for 1st student. But then it halts, if I press any number & press enter, it asks for next grade & so on. And this way it prints average at the end. If I enter not allowed input, it catches that.
What is wrong in this code.

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numStudents, sum=0;
        int[] grades;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of students : ");
        numStudents = in.nextInt();

        grades = new int[numStudents];
      //System.out.println(grades.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter grade of student "+i+" :");
              grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
              if(grades[i]>100 || grades[i]<0)
                {
                  System.out.println("It is not a valid number!");
                  i--;
                  continue;
                }

              //grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
              sum+=grades[i];
        }

        System.out.print("Average grades are: "+sum/numStudents);

        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: *What is wrong in this code.* -- You tell us! In what way doesn't it behave as expected?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger ?

Comment: @aioobe: As I told in my OP, after getting 1st input for grade, it then halt. Then if I randomly type a number on console & press enter, it displays msg for next grade input. in this way when all grades done,, say way I enter a random number & press enter. It shows result. Though if I put wrong input i.e. grade <0 || grade > 100, it shows error msg & directly ask for same grade again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your temp variable, create a variable like this:

`int grade = in.nextInt()`

Then check `if(grade > 100 || grade < 0) // error message`

Don't use `in.next()` twice, because it then asks the user for another number.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Probably I even don't need an additional var. I can assign directly to array. & if wrong value, same index will be updated in next input. I updates the code in OP.